# Typescript Namespacing

Tags: typescript

I am writing a typescript library where I would like to implement my own `Gamepad` class. This does not extend the existing HTML5 `Gamepad` class but I don't want to override the original one either.

How do I utilize some sort of namespace in typescript so:

- Consumers can call Library.Gamepad to get my gamepad class.
- I can still get the original `Gamepad` class when writing my library.

For the second point, I know I can use aliases when importing, but how to I access the original `Gamepad` class when writing my own:

```js
export default class Gamepad {
  nativePad: Gamepad | null = null; // I would like this to reference the native Gamepad typing

  constructor() {}
}
```

Basically, I want to a way to work around using a name like `MyGamepad` to avoid the conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems silly, but you can probably refer to the global object with `window.Gamepad`

Comment: Using ```nativePad: typeof window.Gamepad | null = null;``` seems like the best way, thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify for others - ```InstanceType<typeof window.Gamepad>``` is what you want. Not using ```InstanceType<T>``` will give you the class rather than the instance type.